# NodeJS app with express and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express

I'm writing this mini RESTful app that takes requests to different URLs. For that I'm using nodejs, and express to set up the different paths. As a database, I'm planning on using monogoDB (the node-mongodb-native by christkv).

My code (that doesn't include mongo attempts) looks like this:

app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express = require('express')
    , routes = require('./routes')
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var client = new Db('test', new Server('127.0.0.1', 27017, {}));    

// Configuration

app.configure(function() {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function() {
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function() {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

var insertData = function(err, collection) {
    collection.insert({name: "Kristiono Setyadi"});
    collection.insert({name: "Meghan Gill"});
    collection.insert({name: "Spiderman"});
}



// Routes
app.post('/', routes.syncServiceIndex);

app.post('/syncService', routes.synchServicePost);
app.get('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/sync', routes.synchServiceSync);
app.post('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/push', routes.synchServicePush);
app.del('/syncService/:syncServiceUser', routes.synchServiceDel);

app.post('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/contacts/push', routes.synchServiceContactsPush);
app.get('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/contacts/sync', routes.synchServiceContactsSync);

app.post('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/contacts/', routes.synchServiceContactsPost);
app.get('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/contacts/:contactId', routes.synchServiceContactsGet);
app.put('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/contacts/:contactId', routes.synchServiceContactsPut);
app.del('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/contacts/:contactId', routes.synchServiceContactsDel);

app.listen(3000);



console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

and for the sake of keeping different components in different files, this is my file with the code for each URL:

index.js

```
//var ObjectID = db.bson_serializer.ObjectID;
exports.syncServiceIndex = function(req, res) {
    console.log('syncServiceIndex');
    //console.log("BODY:" + JSON.stringify(req.body));

    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
};

exports.synchServicePost = function(req, res) {
    console.log('synchServicePost');
    console.log("BODY:" + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
};

exports.synchServiceSync = function(req, res) {
    console.log('synchServiceSync');
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
};

exports.synchServicePush = function(req, res) {
    console.log('synchServicePush');
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
};

exports.synchServiceDel = function(req, res) {
    console.log('synchServiceDel');
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
};

exports.synchServiceDel = function(req, res) {
    console.log('synchServiceDel');
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
};

exports.synchServiceContactsPush = function(req, res) {
    console.log('synchServiceContactsPush');
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
};

exports.synchServiceContactsSync = function(req, res) {
    console.log('synchServiceContactsSync');
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
};

exports.synchServiceContactsPost = function(req, res) {
    console.log('synchServiceContactsPost');
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
};

exports.synchServiceContactsGet = function(req, res) {
    console.log('synchServiceContactsGet');
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
};

exports.synchServiceContactsPut = function(req, res) {
    console.log('synchServiceContactsPut');
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
};

exports.synchServiceContactsDel = function(req, res) {
    console.log('synchServiceContactsDel');
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.send("OK\n");
};
```

From what I saw in some sample codes i've been checking out, I should only really use only one open connection, that is I should have all my code in the

```
client.open(function(err, pClient) {

});
```

call. The problem i'm having though is that I'm not sure how to pass the client or collection so that I can work with the database from the index.js file. Is there a way I can do that in the current layout, or do I have to move some stuff around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap all your routes into the callback and set `req.mongoClient = pClient` in a middleware, for example:

```
client.open(function(err, pClient) {
  clientMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
    req.mongoClient = pClient;
    next();
  }
  // your routes here, with clientMiddleware
  app.post('/', clientMiddleware, routes.syncServiceIndex);
  app.post('/syncService', clientMiddleware, routes.synchServicePost);
  app.get('/syncService/:syncServiceUser/sync', clientMiddleware, routes.synchServiceSync);
  // etc.
});
```

You can now get the client by using `req.mongoClient` in all the routes.

Comment: Why should one wrap routes in the client.open callback? Do I have to do this if I use mongoskin too?

Comment: Well you would do that if you would want mongoClient to be easily accessible in the routes/controller. You don't need to do this, it's a matter of preference.